# Replace a gwt generated jar with a newer version

Tags: gwt, patch, gxt

I've developed a GWT+GXT based web application. Recently we run into an issue that I was able to fix easily.

However when I generate the jar file from the tag, including the backport of the fix, even though I replace the old jar with the new one the fix has no effect.

On the other end if I generate the whole WAR everything works fine, but because of the size of it i'd rather like to be able to provide the patch as a jar file.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't do it. You can't guarantee, that all works together. And as another minus: Noone will ever know, what is really deployed on the server. Create a war and deploy it. If your application is to big, try to split it or use another deployment type (like WAB-files in geronimo)

Comment: I don't understand your question. GWT client Java is compiled to Javascript, not Java bytecode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623764/need-help-packaging-a-gwt-library-module-into-a-jar/8651957#8651957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jar` file only contains Java sources and compiled Java - when you compile GWT, that produces JavaScript. This is what the `war` file contains, in addition to all of the other contents. In order to properly update your application, you need to update the compiled JavaScript.

The easiest way to do this, as you've noticed, is to replace the entire war file. If you want to keep the changes to a minimum, you could try just replacing the compiled JS directory and the jar file, but you'll want to be careful that you get the right directory - and all of the contents.